# Upload file to Azure Datalake doens't work from SQL Server Agent job

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, azure, azure-data-lake

I have created an executable file using C# which uploads file from local to Azure Data-lake. When I run this executable by double clicking on it, it works.
But if I try to run the same executable using SQL Server Agent job I get the below errors:

> ADLException
>      Http Status: 0
>      Http Message: 
>      Remote Exception Name: 
>      Server Trace Id: 
>      Exception Message: Error in creating file ****.
>   Operation: CREATE failed with  Unknown Error: Unable to connect to the remote server.
>   Last encountered exception thrown after 5 tries. [Unable to connect to the remote server,Unable to connect to the remote server,Unable to connect to the remote server,Unable to connect to the remote server,Unable to connect to the remote server]
>   [ServerRequestId:]
>      Exception Stack Trace:    at Microsoft.Azure.DataLake.Store.AdlsClient.CreateFile(String filename, IfExists mode, String octalPermission, Boolean createParent)
>      at AzureDataLakeFileIO.Program.Main(String[] args)

Note that I'm running the job using proxy account with my user-ID.
[image]

Comment: Are you referring to Data Lake Gen1 or Gen2?  They are very different.

Comment: Is it working from the Agent if, instead of using a user proxy, you temporarily set the user you are running the .exe with?